# Hybris validation framework vs Drools engine

Tags: e-commerce, drools, sap-commerce-cloud

Our project is an E commerce B2B hybris. Currently we are using DROOLS engine to manage business logic/rules. Which one should we use for better performance and time efficiency: DROOLS or Hybris Validator?

Comment: Why don't yo try both with *your* data and *your* rules?

Comment: Hi Launa,thanks for your reply.but going for both drools and hybris validation framework will be more complicated.My only concern is which one among these two is more performance efficient and easy to manage/maintain.

Comment: Nobody will be able to provide good reason without knowing your use cases, environment, etc. - Yes, preparing such decisions is costly, but a poor decision may turn out to be much more expensive.

Comment: You won't get around some investigation. If you are already somewhat proficient in hybris development you will find the validation framework not very difficult to learn. It is not as powerful as drools, so you should first look at whether all your current logic/rules can be implemented with the validation framework alone. 
Hybris currently has no integration points with drools which might change in the future as there is some internal development/evaluation around drools going on, but even if it does it might still be a somewhat limited drools integration.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, Hybris Validator is your choice. 
Drools is not used for data validation but promotion，coupon and personalization  ...

Answer (score 0):

Drools is to use for complex promotions.

You can still use the discount for simpler kind of promotions.

Note that having too much Drools rules can be a performance issue so think about using classic discount if it can be enough.